# winapi change brightness

Tags: delphi, screen, brightness

What winapi's are there to change the screen's brightness?

[image]

I've been attempting to look for an example or API I can use for Delphi but have not found anything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Starting with Windows Vista you can use the [`GetMonitorBrightness`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd692939%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`SetMonitorBrightness`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd692972%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions.

```
function GetMonitorBrightness(
  hMonitor : THandle;
  var   pdwMinimumBrightness : DWORD;
  var   pdwCurrentBrightness : DWORD;
  var   pdwMaximumBrightness : DWORD
) : BOOL; stdcall ; external 'Dxva2.dll' name 'GetMonitorBrightness';


function SetMonitorBrightness(
  hMonitor : THandle;
  dwNewBrightness : DWORD
): BOOL; stdcall ; external 'Dxva2.dll' name 'SetMonitorBrightness';
```

Another option is use the [`WmiSetBrightness`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394549%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method of the [`WmiMonitorBrightnessMethods`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394538%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI Class.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  ActiveX,
  Variants,
  ComObj;

procedure  SetBrightness(Timeout : Integer; Brightness : Byte);
var
  FSWbemLocator : OLEVariant;
  FWMIService   : OLEVariant;
  FWbemObjectSet: OLEVariant;
  FWbemObject   : OLEVariant;
  oEnum         : IEnumvariant;
  iValue        : LongWord;
begin;
  FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  FWMIService   := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer('localhost', 'root\WMI', '', '');
  FWbemObjectSet:= FWMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT * FROM WmiMonitorBrightnessMethods Where Active=True','WQL',$00000020);
  oEnum         := IUnknown(FWbemObjectSet._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  while oEnum.Next(1, FWbemObject, iValue) = 0 do
  begin
    FWbemObject.WmiSetBrightness(Timeout, Brightness);
    FWbemObject:=Unassigned;
  end;
end;


begin
 try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    try
      SetBrightness(5, 100);
    finally
      CoUninitialize;
    end;
 except
    on E:EOleException do
        Writeln(Format('EOleException %s %x', [E.Message,E.ErrorCode]));
    on E:Exception do
        Writeln(E.Classname, ':', E.Message);
 end;
 Writeln('Press Enter to exit');
 Readln;
end.
```

**Note**: These functions are supported if the [GetMonitorCapabilities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd692940%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function returns the MC_CAPS_BRIGHTNESS flag.