# Show the Windows 8 brightness slider via native c++

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, windows-8, brightness, screen-brightness

I'm working on an app where I need to change the brightness. However, I want the user to be aware of the relative brightness by seeing the built in brightness slider they're used to. Also- this designed to run only on laptops or tablets so the displays should support programmatic brightness.

[image] *Note: This image was stolen from [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027126/winapi-change-brightness/16028102#16028102)

I was hoping it would automatically show up when I changed the brightness programmatically but no luck there. I tried doing so with WmiSetBrightness() and with PowerWriteACValueIndex() but neither of them showed the slider.

TL;DR I want to programmatically invoke the slider to show the user what the current brightness level is. Any ideas?